# Angular 12 SSR - routes having canActivate does not work on page reload

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, reload, ngxs

I have angular 12 project in which I have applied Angular universal(ssr). I have deployed that project on nginx server.

Application works fine but if user press browser reload for routes on which I have applied canActivate does not reloads properly.

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
{ path: "user-profile", component: UserProfileComponent,canActivate : [AuthGuard] },
```

**auth.guard.ts**

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): boolean | UrlTree {
    if (!this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.openConfirmationDialog(route);

      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
  openConfirmationDialog(route) {
 
      Swal.fire({
        title: this.title,
        text: this.text,
        //icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: this.okButton,
        cancelButtonText: this.cancelButton
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
          this.navigation(route)
        } else if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel) {
        
        }
      });
  }
  navigation(route) {
    console.log('User confirmed:');

    this.router.navigate(['login'], { queryParams: { retUrl: route.url } });
  }
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
    let input = new FormData();
    const headers = {
      "APP-TOKEN": "GV5TmkI8lCyPqBTLExji",
      "Accept-Language": this.currentLang,
    };
    input.append("email", email);
    input.append("password", password);
    return this.http
      .post<any>(`${this.serverUrl}api/v1/login`, input, { headers: headers })
      .pipe(
        map((user) => {
          return user;
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

      isLoggedIn() {
        if (localStorage.getItem("currentUser")) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
```

**on login form submit**

```
onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.errorMessage = "";
    this.isErrorOccured = false;
    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
      this.errorMessage = "Invalid details";
      return;
    }

    this.loading = true;
    if (!this.localFlag) {
      this.authService
        .login(this.f.email.value, this.f.password.value)
        .subscribe(
          (data) => {

            if (data["status"] === true || data["count"] === true) {
              this.loading = false;
              this.errorMessage = "";
              this.isErrorOccured = false;

              window.localStorage.setItem(
                "currentUser",
                JSON.stringify(data["data"])
              );
              window.localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", "true");
              window.localStorage.removeItem("guest-user-id");

              localStorage.setItem("loginCall", "true");
              this.router.navigate(['/user-timeline']);
            } else {
          
              this.notifyService.showError(data["message"], "");

              this.isErrorOccured = true;
              this.loading = false;
              window.localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", "false");
            }
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log("error:", error);
            this.loading = false;
            window.localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", "false");
          }
        );
    } else {
    }
  }
```

If I check localstorage `currentUser` value on page reload then its giving `null`. I searched and applied `rxjs` techniques, `ngrx`, `ngxs` to retain value but that also not working in my project flow.

What should I do ? is there any other way to validate authentication for routes ? or how should I retain values on page reload?

Please help and guide. Thanks

Comment: I think you need to rethink your authentication guard. Your server cannot know what your user's localStorage content is. You could rely on cookies

Comment: Could you detail what does mean _ does not reloads properly_

Comment: There is a slight difference when using window.localstorage and localstorage in case of SSL. put window. in isLogged() and test

Comment: @Vega when we use browser reload then ideally page reloads and shows data again means it restart again. In my case locally when I reload some pages/routes which has `canAcitivate` applied does not reloads but only shows buffering in that tab. When I debugged then I come to know that I am checking localStorage key `currentUser` in canActivate. There I gets null for the key when I click browser reload. I have tried many techniques to retain localStorage value but nothing working in my project. so looking alternative for canActivate or any techniques to retain values in already built project.

Comment: @Vega I have applied SSR in project where i installed MockBrowser for window and localstorage to remove errors related to that for SSR.

Comment: SSR means server side rendering. I have used angular universal for that in my angular project.

Comment: It seems that current user is not set on this line:                 JSON.stringify(data["data"]). Did you check/log data object? does it have necessary info?

Comment: @Sergey I tried cookies but it also does not works in SSR on browser page reload.

Comment: @Vega I gets values of localStorage first but when user press browser reload or hard refresh (f5) then localStorage does not have values that why my `canActivate` not works

Comment: Do you manually erase local storage values somewhere in your code?

Comment: @Vega local storage values will be cleared on logout. but before clicking on logout, when I click browser reload (f5) localstorage becomes null/undefined.

Comment: Can you find the part of the code that clears the local storage, because it is not a built-in functionallity of reload. I really think caActivate should stay as is

Answer (score 0):

SSR means "Server Side Rendering", that means that your angular code is being executed in the server and then the generated HTML is being sent to the browser.

**Whats Happening**

When you reload the page, the browser makes a get request to the URL. Along with that request, the local storage data is not sent to the server (only cookies set on that domain are sent to the server). Thats why when the server executes the AuthGuard and when AuthService tries to read the local storage, the local storage is empty hence the expected User data is null.

**Solution**

Instead of using local storage to store the user data, use cookies. To interact with cookies you can use [ngx-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service) . This packages also supports SSR.
You can read more about cookies [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies). Also be aware about the limitation of cookies ([link](http://browsercookielimits.iain.guru/)).